# How does compiling happen only for the first time in projectless development?

Tags: asp.net

I read these words in a book:

> **Projectless development simplifies debugging**: When creating a web project, you must recompile the entire application when you change a single page. With projectless development, each page is compiled separately, *and the page is only compiled when you request it for the first time.*

How does compiling happen only for the first time in projectless development?
Should it recompile every time I run the page to reflect the new code I wrote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS compiles it. When a page changes and is uploaded again, IIS will compile it again.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466.aspx) topic on MSDN, in particular the section headed `Automatic Compilation`.

This should apply to other web servers as well (XPS, apache with mod_mono) as can be seen in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/introtomono2.aspx).

Comment: And what if the dear asker isn't using IIS, but another server? :)

Comment: @Time Machine - From reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/introtomono2.aspx), I would say the same.

Comment: @ismailawy4ever - I don't think so. From your quote: `the page is only compiled when you request it for the first time.`. Note the reference to a _request_. This would be a request to a web server.

Comment: you mean that when i request a page from a website on a server,the server will compile it once and gives the page to me unless this page changed?

Comment: @ismailawy4ever - If not compiled before it will be compiled and served. If it changes, it is not compiled.